# Bash function to kill process

Tags: bash

I made an alias for this function in order to kill processes in bash:

On my **.bashrc** file

```
  kill_process(){
    # $1 being a parameter for the process name
    kill $(ps ax | grep "$1" | awk '{print $1}')
}

alias kill_process=kill_process
```

So, suppose I want to kill the `meteor` process:

*Let's see all meteor processes:*

```
ps aux | grep 'meteor' | awk '{print $2}' 

21565
21602
21575
21546
```

*Calling the `kill_process` function with the alias*

```
kill_process meteor

bash: kill: (21612) - No such process
```

So, the `kill_process` function effectively terminates the `meteor` processes, but it's `kill` command looks for an inexistent pid. Notice the pid `21612` wasn't listed by `ps aux | grep`.  **Any ideas to improve the `kill_process` function to avoid this?**

Comment: Probably one of the original list of four process ids was the `grep 'meteor'` command (because the invocation line of that matches the pattern `meteor`). And one of the process ids that are generated by the `$(ps ax | grep "$1" | awk ...)` line is *that* grep process. But by the time that list of pids gets given to `kill`, that grep process has ceased.

Comment: Or perhaps just use `pkill`.

Comment: That alias serves no purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of killing processes by name is using `killall`, as Swoogan suggests in his answer.

As to your `kill_process` function, the `grep` expression that filters `ps` will match the very own `grep` process (you can see this running the pipeline without `awk`), but by the time `kill` is invoked, that process is no longer running. That's the message you see.

Each time you run the command, `grep` runs again with a new PID: that's the reason you can't find it on the list when you test it.

You could:

1. Run `ps` first, pipe it into a file or variable, then `grep`
2. Filter `grep`'s PID out of the list
3. (Simpler) supress `kill` output:

   ```
   kill $(...) 2>/dev/null
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I think in your case the killall command would do what you want:

```
killall NAME
```

Comment: +1 Note that, unlike the snippet above, this is not a regex-match. It will only `kill` processes with the exact name.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn contrariwise, kill with pattern matching is a mite hazardous when the pattern is something like `p`.